# url rewrite without redirect by using mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to change an url without page refresh and redirect in .htaccess

I need to change only the url address:

From `example.domain.com`

To `www.newdomain.com`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

Comment: Thanks your replied. But I want to change the url but not redirect to the new url. is it possible?

Comment: You cannot actually change the url that's shown on the browser, if that's what you actually need

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite **example.domain.com** to **newdomain.com** via apache proxy module (P flag). If mod-proxy is enabled, you can use the following rule in **example.domain.com/.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```